# Nginx configuration - https works but not http

Tags: nginx, debian

I have an issue with a freshly configured Nginx setup on Debian 9.
My site loads fine using https, but I get a 404 Not Found when I access it using http.

I tried removing the ssl certificate, it works however i need the location /webex/receive in https and /ping and /mailgun in http.
See my edited down server block:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

   location /ping {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /mailgun {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /webex/receive {
        proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

}
```

All location (/ping, /mailgun and /webex/receive) work in https but I only want /webex/receive in https and the others locations /mailgun and /ping in http.

Comment: Similar: https://serverfault.com/questions/10854/nginx-https-serving-with-same-config-as-http

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/xx.xx.xx.xxx/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name xx.xx.xx.xxx www.xx.xx.xx.xxx;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /ping {
                 proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000;
        }
        location /mailgun {
                 proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:3000;
        }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location /webex/receive {
             proxy_pass http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:8080;
        }

}
```